# Handle action onClick in DatePicker Antd

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, antd

I have an antd DatePicker at the header of an collapse as below

```
<DatePicker
  showNow
  allowClear={false}
  className={styles.edit_start_time}
  value={moment(experiment.start_time)}
  format="MMMM DD, YYYY h:mm A"
  addonBefore="Start At:"
  onChange={handleExperimentStartTimeChange}
  showTime={{ use12Hours: true, format: "h:mm A" }}
  onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()} />
```

The issue I am facing is every time I click on the date or time fields the collapsible is expanding and closing which not not have happened considering  `onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}` which I have added.

Can anyone help me with this one.

Thanks.

Comment: You should also provide the source of `collapse`.

Comment: I using the simple antd collapse where there is component for DatePicker in the extra children of the Collapse header

Comment: Check out my answer. And if it works for you then mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `header` as the `collapsible` property of `Panel` will work for you.

So, only clicking the header will trigger collapse/expand.

So, `Panel` element will be like:

```
<Panel
    header="This is panel header 1"
    key="1"
    collapsible="header"
    extra={genExtra()}
>
```

and your `DatePicker` component:

```
const genExtra = () => (
  <DatePicker
    showNow
    allowClear={false}
    value={moment(experiment.start_time)}
    format="MMMM DD, YYYY h:mm A"
    addonBefore="Start At:"
    onChange={handleExperimentStartTimeChange}
    showTime={{ use12Hours: true, format: "h:mm A" }}
  />
);
```

You don't even have to `stopPropagation`.

**Working demo** at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/extra-node-antd4150-forked-v8ik1?file=/index.js).